# Pi not working on my VGA monitor

Tags: display

I have brought a Rasberry Pi 4 model B and have used Rasbian on it.It works fine in my 45 inch hdmi input TV but when i tried to use it in my PC VGA monitor of resolution 1336x768  using a HDMI to VGA converter box the screen shows error message with 'D-sub 67khz /60Khz' and just blank display.I don't know what all changes should i do in my config.txt file..I tried boostig the HDMI signal to 11 but it didnt work..My monitor is LG FLATRON E1942 Vga,60 Hz display. Can anyone help me solving this?The HDMI to Vga converter i used is a usb powered one and i have also tried it also with a non-powered hdmi to Vga converter but that didnt worked too..

Comment: Try this Google search https://www.google.com/search?q=1366x768+site%3Araspberrypi.org it will reveal a lot of threads on the Raspberry Pi forum about this feature on an RPi4B.

Answer (score 1):

Gut feel it that its the HDMI to VGA adapter / cable - first point to check is if they say they are PI compatible or not. I had nightmares getting one to work with some (including my current) Mac boxes - at one point ONLY Maplin had working ones.

Try adding the following to config.txt (one block at a time with POWER CYCLE):

```
hdmi_safe = 1
hdmi_ignore_edid_audio=1


hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=1
hdmi_ignore_edid_audio


hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=86
hdmi_ignore_edid_audio
```

Obviously, make sure the cable is in port 0 (the one closest to the USB-C power).